# Django Management Command Triggers URLs When Checking Database Connection

Tags: python, django

I've encountered an unexpected behavior while working on a Django project involving a custom management command. The command I've created, named `wait_for_db`, is intended to test whether the database connection is ready before proceeding with other tasks. However, when I trigger this command using `python manage.py wait_for_db`, it seems to be invoking some URLs, leading to database-related errors.

I've structured the management command to primarily check the database connection's readiness without interacting with URLs or the web server. The goal is to ensure that the database is available before proceeding with other operations.

Here's a simplified version of my management command:

```py
"""
Django command to wait for the database to be available.
"""
import time

from psycopg2 import OperationalError as Psycopg2OpError

from django.db.utils import OperationalError
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    """Django command to wait for database."""

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """Entrypoint for command."""
        self.stdout.write('Waiting for database...')
        db_up = False
        while db_up is False:
            try:
                self.check(databases=['default'])
                db_up = True
            except (Psycopg2OpError, OperationalError):
                self.stdout.write('Database unavailable, waiting 1 second...')
                time.sleep(1)

        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Database available!'))
```

Despite my best efforts, when I execute `python manage.py wait_for_db`, it seems to trigger some URLs or components that access the database. As a result, I receive errors indicating that the app is attempting to access a database table during the process of checking if the database connection is ready.

Is there a specific reason why running a management command would lead to URL-related interactions and database access? How can I modify my management command to solely check the database connection's readiness without causing these unintended side effects?

Any insights or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**Environment:**

- Django version: 4.1
- Python version: 3.10
- Database: Postgres

Comment: not sure what `BaseCommand.check` does but my `try` block is structured as `from django.db import connections` then `db_conn = connections["default"]` then `db_conn.cursor()`

Comment: I think it does the same think as `check`

Comment: looks like `BaseCommand.check` does more than just test your database connection https://github.com/django/django/blob/11920e77959deaa65eb86ccc5d39da903fd3dd41/django/core/management/base.py#L479-L484